# "Uncaught ReflectionException: Class DOMDocument does not exist" error

Tags: drush, composer

On Ubuntu 16.04, I installed Drush using Composer: `composer global require drush/drush:~8`. Installation succeeded, but running `drush --version`, I got this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class DOMDocument does
>   not exist in
>   /.../composer/vendor/consolidation/output-formatters/src/Transformations/DomToArraySimplifier.php:24

What do I do now?

Answer (score 26):

DOMDocument is included in the extension php-xml.  To install it on ubuntu, run:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Same problem on my machine, where I have php-5.6 and php-7.0 installed.

To fix this issue I have installed `php5.6-xml` and `php7.0-xml` too.

Comment: this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Checking your php version first by command line:

```
php -v
```

and install the corresponding php-xml extension (eg: php5.6-xml; php7.0-xml; php7.1-xml; php7.2-xml).